# Is it possible to output on screen the content of a certain memory address in a C program?

Tags: c

For debugging reasons, how can one in a C program print some memory address?

For instance, how should I do to print the content of address 0x611268 in form of a 4 byte float?

I know I could use a debugger, but I mean, to print out in screen.

Comment: Why would you want to show memory as a float?  Unless you know that the memory contains a float, the output will be meaningless.  Far better to display hex values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  // pointer to int (4bytes) that points to memory address 0x611268
  int* address = (int *)0x611268; 

  printf("Memory address is: 0x%x\n", address);

  // Note that this address should exist on your process' memory or 
  // the line below will cause a Segmentation Fault
  *address = 0xdead; //assign a value to that address

  printf("Content of that address is: 0x%x\n", *address);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: -1 for using implicit conversion to `int` and %x instead of %p

Comment: I'm not sure if that is reason enough to justify a -1, but I understand why you did it.

Comment: There *is* no implicit conversion here; arguments that are part of a variable argument list go through the default promotions (which doesn't affect pointer types) and then are passed as-is.  You either need to explicitly cast to `(unsigned)`, or use `%p`.

Answer (score 4):

More correctly, `printf("Value = %f\n", *((float*)0x611268));`

Of course this assumes the address you've given is in the address space of the process running the `printf`.

Comment: Printing some random piece of memory as a float will give you a totally meaningless float.  The sign, exponent and mantissa won't correspond to the bytes in memory in a readily apparent way.  It would be far better to print it as Hex, as shown by @karlphillip

Comment: I agree, but the OP requested float specifically.

Comment: It also assumes that the address you've given is correctly aligned for access as a `float`.

Answer (score 2):

The correct format specifier to print out contents of pointers is "%p":

```
fprintf(stderr, "myVar contains %p\n", (void*)myVar);
```